# Return Func array from Halide function

Tags: arrays, return, func, halide

I have a function in a Halide program that needs to return an array of Funcs along with a Func. How do I do this?

```
Tuple Func myFunc() {
const int s = 8;
Func pyramid[s];
Func X("X");
......
return Tuple(pyramid[](x,y), X(x,y));
```

predictably does not work as pyramid is not an Expr. I asked ChatGPT but it asked me to list each array element individually in the Tuple constructor. Is there a more compact way? One that doesn't require me to change the return command when I change s?

Another question:
How do I assign a string name to a Func array? As you see above, I have assigned the string name "X" to the Func X but I'd like to do so to pyramid also.

Comment: If you add a bit more context about what you're trying to actually do (not how you think you want to do it at a low level) it might help people understand and suggest effective approaches.

Comment: I'm trying to create a Laplacian Pyramid and return it. 
Each level of the pyramid is a separate Func. The 8 levels in the pyramid form an array of Funcs.

See an example of Laplacian Pyramid at https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/main/apps/local_laplacian/local_laplacian_generator.cpp
This example does not run into the problem I have as it consumes the pyramid in the same function that it creates it in.

Comment: Are you hoping to return the constituent Funcs that make up the levels of the pyramid from a C++ function to use elsewhere in the construction of the same Halide pipeline, or are you hoping to create a Halide pipeline that produces separate buffers for all of the pyramid levels? (These are different goals that work at different levels of metaprogramming.)

Comment: The former. Thanks. I’m a beginner in Halide and even my C++ is rusty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to return multiple `Func`s for later use inside the construction of a larger Halide pipeline, you don't need to make a Halide-level object to group them together. Instead, any C++ object can carry them. e.g., you could return a `std::vector<Halide::Func>` from your C++ function, and then have later Halide code reference any of those.

The key thing to understand is that there are really two **"stages"** of program here, the C++ code which *constructs* the Halide program (the first stage), and then the Halide program itself which is evaluated later (the second stage, independently of the C++ that constructed it) to produce pixels. This is more clear and explicit if you use the ahead-of-time compilation model (e.g., starting from [tutorial 10](https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_10_aot_compilation_generate.html)), but the idea still applies even when you're using it in JIT mode.